# Simple date formatting question yyyymmdd

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, date, formatting

Wondering about the best way to turn a string like "yyyymmdd" into a string with the format "mm-dd-yyyy". Tried NSDateFormatter with no luck. Any help is appreciated!

My solution is as follows:

```
NSString *dateString = @"22082011;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, YYYY"];
dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
[dateFormatter release];
```

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you want. Are you trying to rearrange the format string?

Comment: I just want a rearranged string, preferably in a more elegant way than just going through it and using substringWithRange, substringToIndex, etc.

Comment: it would be better to turn it into "mm/dd/yyyy", because normally the "-" is used with the international notation (yyyy-mm-dd), "/" with the american one (mm/dd/yyyy) and "." to the European one (dd.mm.yyyy).

Comment: Why are you trying to rearrange it?

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip. Any idea what the best way to do this is?

Comment: For display purposes. I'm reading in JSON that gives me a format of "yyyymmdd". I want to be able to display "mm-dd-yyyy"

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but consider displaying it as "yyyy-mm-dd".  This is the international standard format; google "ISO 8601".  Both "mm-dd-yyyy" and "mm/dd/yyyy" are potentially ambiguous; is 01/02 January 2 or February 1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will first need to parse it:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
```

and then you can use this:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *myFormattedDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *dateStr = @"20081122";

// Convert string to date object
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];  

// Convert date object to desired output format
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE MMMM d, YYYY"];
dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];  
[dateFormat release];
```

From a [helpful article.](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/date-formatters-examples-take-3.html)