# Extract Multiple Strings from Single String

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I am working on string e.g `@"78912345"`. I want to extract three string from it, first four characters as StringOne, then 5th and 6th character as StringTwo and 7th and 8th character as StringThree. 
Please guide. Thanks

Comment: @AnoopVaidya actually i am extracting string to Validate Date. Like first four are for Year, then two are for Month and last two for Days.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya that will be changing all the time but he length will remain the same.

Comment: The NSString documentation has a section "Dividing Strings" ...

Comment: What is truly amazing here is the number of incorrect answers that were up-voted! Also that the OP did not appear to do any research such as looking at the `NSString` documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `NSMakeRange` and subStringWithRange....

```
NSString *string = @"78912345";
NSString *first, *second, *third;

first=[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 4)];
second=[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(first.length, 2)];
third=[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(first.length+second.length, 2)];
```

As your length is fixed...

You can do :

```
first=[string substringToIndex:4]; //will give you first four chars
second=[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(first.length, 2)]; //
third=[string substringFromIndex:string.length-2]; //last two
```

**EDIT :**  *(Thanks to SPA for noticing he wanted for Date)*

As you want to parse the number to year, month and date, you can use this as :

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:date]; 

NSInteger year = [components year]     
NSInteger month = [components month] 
NSInteger day = [components day]
```

Comment: In the first and last cases see: `substringToIndex:4` and `substringFromIndex:6`.

Comment: @Zaph: yes you are right, once I thought of that, but as the lenght is not sure if it is always same so i went on to do like this...

Comment: first=[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 4)];
 this will work on first=[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 4)]; ??

Comment: @AmiriDev: updated the answer, as per zaph and your comment.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Sorry dear it was mistake. can you add me to Skype? amir.ios

Answer (score 2):

Use this method to extract what you want:

```
NSString *result = [baseString substringWithRange:range];
```

If you want the first four characters, then your range is:

```
NSMakeRange(0,4)
```

If you want the last 2 characters:

```
NSMakeRange(6,2)
```

In general:

```
NSMakeRange(firstIndex,lenght)
```

Comment: The last 2 character code is incorrect, should be `NSMakeRange(6,2)`.

Answer (score 2):

if it is always a date of the format YYYMMDD you want to parse, then use the NSDateFormatter see [Simple date formatting question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001927/simple-date-formatting-question-yyyymmdd/7001986#7001986)

Comment: Also NSDateComponents.

Answer (score 1):

```
      NSString *yearStr  = [valueStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 4)];
      NSString *monthStr = [valueStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(4, 2)];
      NSString *dayStr   = [valueStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(6, 2)];
```

i Hope it will work for you. try this...

Comment: It will not work, all of the starts of the ranges are one to great. Try the code, not only will it not produce the correct results it will crash on the last statement.

Comment: Still incorrect and still crashes on the last statement. Actually try your code in Xcode or CodeRunner! Error message: 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString substringWithRange:]: Range {7, 2} out of bounds; string length 8'

Comment: ok now it will work
~NSString *yearStr  = [valueStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 4)];
                    NSString *monthStr = [valueStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(4, 2)];
                    NSString *dayStr   = [valueStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(6, 2)];~